# Move scientific notation exponential to right side of y axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have plotted a figure like this[image]

Now I want to move the scientific notation offset `1e4` to the right of the right y axis, best move it to the upper right of `1.8` label.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
t = ax.yaxis.get_offset_text()
t.set_x(1.1)
```

with `ax` your right axis. However, you cannot change the y position, so if you are not satisfied with it, you can hide the offset text and create it manually at the right position (x,y):

```
ax.yaxis.get_offset_text().set_visible(False)
text(x, y, "1e4")
```